# JavaScript utility for date formatting

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to use a utility function, which I can use as follows:

```
var d = new Date();
formatDate(d, "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
```

I know I can implement this function by myself but I would like to use something "standard". Besides I would like this function to run in both client side and server side (i.e. in browser and `node.js`) and not to bring unnecessary dependencies. (for example, I would not like to use a `jQuery` function)

There are a lot of Q&A about date formatting but I am still not sure if there is a utility

Comment: Why don't you just use the stuff that's already in the `Date` object? Also, you say you don't want unnecessary dependencies but you do want to use *jQuery*, the #1 unnecessary dependency *ever*?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Sorry. I meant I would *not* like to use `jQuery`. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: What formats do you need? Only that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lightweight library is what you need. Just remove unwanted parts of it.

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out

### [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

It should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) with the folowing code:

```
var d = Date.today().set({ day: 15, hour: 8, minute: 30 });
d.toString("YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
```